# Scammer spam autocompletes when entering team name in profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, spam, jobs

> [image]

When I type "Google", "Microsoft", "Norton", "Canon", "Lexmark", or any of several other company names into the *Company Name* field in the *Career* section of my Stack Overflow profile, most of the suggestions are advertisements for known scammers.

This seems bad.

Comment: Looks like SE has been hacked, in a way. That is clear spam, coming from SE server side.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I was wondering if it might be old spam companies on Careers which were soft-deleted, but this view doesn't filter them.

Comment: No, the search is not limited to companies who got pages in Jobs. More likely that some external search SE use has been compromised.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Good point. I noticed a few entries for companies that shut down more than a few years ago, which might suggest that the data source has been polluted for a while.

Comment: I am tagging this [status-reproduced] instead of [status-completed], since there is far more to do here.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is bad data coming from CrunchBase - I am working to address it now.

---

**Update:** I have done a huge amount of cleanup from the data source and just deployed a new Elastic indexing using it. Here's the old vs. new:

[image: old]

[image: new]

There's a x2 factor of replication, which means there were 59,494 entries removed from the index. Here's a current test:

[image: test]

Note there's still a crap entry there, so I did a good purge but far from perfect. We wanted to address this as soon as possible though, so a quick first pass it is. Hopefully this removed most of the immediate spam. Please feel free to comment here on additional finds and I'll take another pass Monday at cleaning this up further.

On a personal note: I pushed for this. I pushed to buy a clean data source to prevent duplication and have a good user experience with developer stories. This is not what we intended to do and I'm pissed. We also should have checked this further before indexing for developer story and that's on me - I failed here.

I'm sorry this ever showed up on our website. We'll be adding checks to, I sincerely hope, prevent this from ever happening again.

Comment: Nothing but pain so far from this dataset... :-/ that's totally not your fault.

Comment: So CrunchBase  was hacked? Or is it spammy by design and nobody except you care?

Comment: This appears to be related: [Jobs company page spam](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326468/jobs-company-page-spam). :(